# How can I search for and delete an array element in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, search, collections

I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
 (
  [start] => DateTime Object
  (
  )

  [end] => DateTime Object
  (
  )

  [comment] => A comment.
 )

 [1] => Array
 (
  [start] => DateTime Object
  (
  )

  [end] => DateTime Object
  (
  )

  [comment] => Another comment.
 )
)
```

I would like to create a function that deletes an element (start,end,comment) from the array that matches the functions input, and returns false if it doesn't exist. Is there already a PHP function that does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess you mean [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
while (($pos = array_search($input, $multiArray)) !== false) {
    unset($multiArray[$pos]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.  You could do:

```
function array_remove(&$array, $search, $strict = false) { 
    $keys = array_keys($array, $search, $strict);
    if(!$keys)
        return false;
    foreach($keys as $key)
        unset($array[$key]);
    return count($keys);
}
```

Unlike using `array_search()`, this will work if there are multiple matching entries.